# How to get subscription details on azure portal.

Tags: azure, portal

I have recently updated my azure subscription and after that I am unable to see my content or resources on the Azure portal and unable to download the publish profile.

So please help me to find the latest subscription in the new azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

From the top right end, you will have your profile. There you will be able to see the Active Directories available for you. Click on that and it will show a page containing info on "Directories+ Subscriptions". In case you are not able to see the respective subscription in any of those directories, it is requested to raise a Support ticket in the portal itself.

Answer (score -1):

You should ask azure support to help you with this. They can see what you have registered in the portal and if something when wrong. One thing you can try is to open the portal in a private browser session to see if anything is cached or not.